# How to use reset function with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp, reset

Following is the code. I have button called EMPTY ALL button that resets all the input boxes
in the table id= A.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#resetBtn').on('click', function() {

});
</script>

 <table id ="A">

 <input type="text" id="clipSno"><td>

 <select id="year" name="year" onchange="selclsCd()">

 </table>

<div class="area_btnA clfix mgB20">     
    <a id="searchBtn" class="btnA">Empty ALL</a>
</div>
```

Now, what comes in

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#resetBtn').on('click', function() {

});
</script>
```

to empty all the text boxes and select boxes to reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#resetBtn').on('click', function() {
    $("input[type=text], textarea, select").val("");
});
```

In case you just have to reset specific id's then use this -

```
$('#resetBtn').on('click', function() {
    $("#clipSno, #year").val("");
});
```

Comment: For instance, it is <input type="text" id="clipSno">
then it should be like
then what comes in textarea, select??

Comment: sorry but I could not understand your question

Comment: I just edited my question. Could you look at the input box and select box, and tell me how I should code? plz

Comment: i edited my answer check if this is what you are looking for.. Also this would be quite useful to you - http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#resetBtn').on('click', function() {
        $('input[type=text], select, textarea').val('');
    });
});
```

Have fun!